# jquery selecting sibling node of the current node

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I select sibling node of the current node?
Here is the snippet:

```
<div id="main">
    <a class="test" href="test.html">Hello</a>
    <div>Some text</div>
</div>

//script
$(".test").click(function() { $("this:parent > div").toggle(); });
or
$(".test").click(function() { $("this ~ div").toggle(); });
```

None of these works. I know I can access current object using $(this) but in this case I don't know how.

Comment: When you put `this` in quotes, it becomes part of the selector, like you're looking for an element with "this" as the tagName, as in `<this></this>`.

Comment: I was confused about putting quotes! Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few options:

```
$(".test").click(function() { 
    $(this).next('div').toggle(); 
});

$(".test").click(function() { 
    $(this).siblings('div').toggle(); 
});

$(".test").click(function() { 
    $(this).closest('div#main').find('div').toggle(); 
});
```

Just depends on what else is in your HTML markup for which one you want to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to not put `this` in quotes.

```
$(".test").click(function() { 
    $(this).next().toggle(); 
});
```

jQuery has lots of great functions for traversing.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.siblings()`

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to toggle the #main div?  If so, wouldn't `.parent()` give you the parent div?

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

I'd think that you'd have to use something like:

```
$(".test").click(function() { $(this).parent("div").toggle(); });
```

Comment: His question seems pretty clear that he wants the sibling, not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-scope your selector:

```
$(".test").click(function() { $("~ div", this).toggle(); });
```